# Why did no New Testament books mention AD70?

Tags: church-history, new-testament, prophecy, canon, temple

My full question is; which of the New Testament books were written **after AD70?** Assuming there are several, why did none of them mention the 'earth-shattering' events of AD70? The destruction of the temple by Rome fulfilled one of Jesus' own prophecies (Matt. 24:1-3) and its theological significance was central to Christianity. (John 2:19-22) It would have at least been alluded to, surely.

Comment: Partial preterist A/post-millenial eschatology usually interprets much of the prophecy in the New Testament as pointing at the destruction of Jerusalem in A.D. 70. So Matthew and Revelation at the very least speak about it.

Comment: That's because the Temple was no longer theological significant, as Jesus the Lamb of God, had already died to take away the sin of the world. No more sacrifices were needed. Further, the temple was also simply a shadow of what is in heaven. Jesus presented Himself before the true tabernacle in heaven. Why would the Temple hold any significance to the Christian after the death of Jesus?

Comment: Also, in John 2:19-22, Jesus was speaking about His physical body, and not the temple. He was speaking about His death and resurrection.